# IIS Web Deploy's "Import/Export Application" Action Missing?

Tags: iis, webdeploy

I had a working IIS 7.5 with Web Deploy 3.5 configuration such that the "Import/Export Application" feature in the right hand action pane showed up and functioned properly.  Unfortunately I had to remove and reinstall IIS, and now the Import/Export functionality does not show up in the Actions pane, as if Web Deploy was not installed.

I tried to reinstall using the automated installer at http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy, but when I run it, the installer seems to think that Web Deploy is already installed and does not offer me any reinstall/uninstall option.

How can I force a reinstall of WebDeploy or force IIS to recognize that Web Deploy is still installed?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

1. Go to http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy
2. Scroll to the bottom of the page to the "Download Web Deploy" header
3. Click the x86 or x64 link next to your language of choice. Do not click the WebPI link.
4. Once downloaded, click on the installer to open it.
5. Click *Next*
6. Click the *Remove* button
7. Now you can reinstall it using the Web Platform Installer, or just use the standalone.

On a side note...
If you don't see the Deploy options in IIS once you've reinstalled Web Deploy, try running IIS as Administrator. Hope this helps.

Comment: You have to enable an extra “optional windows feature” on modern Windows prior to installing for the installer to put the buttons into inetmgr, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41461305/5120854

Answer (score 22):

I am running IIS on my development machine on Windows 7. Web Deploy 3.6 seem to break something as the Import / Export Application options are not available. Had to uninstall 3.6 via control panel add/remove programs and then install 3.5 via Web PI.

Comment: Me too on Windows 10. Grr. Innocent assumption that 3.6 would be "like 3.5 but a little bit better" resulted in a big waste of time.

Comment: This did it for me. Thank you!

Comment: I found a solution to this (with Web Deploy 3.6), see this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41461305/5120854

Comment: Windows Server 2016 with IIS 10 prefers 3.5 too.  The "Deploy" sub-menu was never available with 3.6

Comment: Windows 7 Pro with IIS 7.5 prefers 3.5 as well. The "Deploy" sub-menu became available once I uninstalled 3.6 and installed 3.5 instead.

Answer (score 8):

I've installed Web Deployment Tool 2.1 then restart IIS Manager and the Import/Export Application appeared.

Comment: I hate uninstalling stuff, as you never know what DLL you're going to clobber, and you get unintended consequences of other things not working. That's why I like this solution -- nothing uninstalled.

Comment: For me IIS Management Service was already installed and IIS Manger was already running as admin and Web Deploy 3.6 was already installed.  Using Microsoft Web Platform installer to install Web Deployment Tool 2.1 worked for me.  This is separate from Web Deploy 3.6--you do not uninstall Web Deploy 3.6, just install Web Deployment Tool 2.1

Answer (score 7):

I was running a 'gallery template' Windows Server 2012 VM on Azure. Web Platform Installer said Web Deploy 3.5 was already installed. At first I thought this neat feature had been removed/moved.

In Add/Remove Programs, saw that Web Deploy 3.6 Beta was installed. Removed it and reinstalled 3.5 (without SQL stuff) via Web PI.

Ran IIS Manager as admin and all works fine.

Update - A new Azure VM also had this problem, but had 3.6 Beta3 installed. Again, removed and reinstalled 3.5 via WebPI.

Answer (score 2):

None of the other answers here fixed this for me with Visual Studio 17 on Windows 10. The fix was here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/230372/web-deply-40-msi-location.html

Web Deploy 4 has moved to be distributed with Visual Studio 2017. This is nuts because the Web Deploy service and the Import/Export tools are for server administrators and not devs. The discussion in the link says they are working on adding Web Deploy 4 to the Web Platform Installer, but have encountered a few issues (read: we didn't create a proper deployment for it the first place.)

The fix for me was to uninstall Web Deploy 4 from Control Panel-Apps & features, then reinstall from the MSI provided with Studio. Look in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages` for a folder like `Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebDeploy.Msi,version=...,chip=x64`. The MSI file is within that. More detail in the link I mentioned.

My guess is if the IIS Manager is not turned on at the time Studio (and therefore Web Deploy) is installed, the hook for Import/Export can't be created.

Answer (score 0):

My situation is slightly different as I never had the import/export menus. For what it's worth:

I tried to install the Web Deploy installer. It said that a newer version was installed. I tried repairing Web Platform Installer. Nothing changed. I tried changing but was told there were individual components. I tried uninstall/reinstalling WebPlatformInstaller.

After that, the IIS Manager showed a `Web Platform Installer` icon under the Management section after restarting, but still no Deploy menu on the right click.

[image: icon screen shot]

Double-clicking that icon started the installer where I could then search for `web deploy`. There was a Web Deployment Tool 2.1 that was not installed. Clicking Add then Install and restarting IIS Manager (not run As Administrator) was all that was needed to get the Deploy menu:

[image]

According to this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-offline-deployment#install-products-and-components), the Web Platform Installer should have started automatically. Never did. But it is in the start menu. The steps are the same weather you start it from IIS Manager or standalone.