# Missing "Import Web Application" option in Web Deploy 3.6

Tags: iis, webdeploy, iis-8.5, webdeploy-3.6

Using Web Deploy 3.6 both on IIS 8.5 (Windows Server 2012 R2) and IIS 7.5 (Windows 7), I cannot find the Deploy -> "Import Web Application" option. The "Export Web Application" is also missing (see screenshot)

[image]

I can still see the "Install Application from Gallery" but that does not really help. All works fine with Web Deploy 3.5.

Are the Import / Export Web Application options removed in 3.6? 
If yes, what is the alternative to deploy a standard ASP.NET MVC app to IIS 8.5 with Web Deploy 3.6?
If not, what do I need to do to enable / see them again?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

WebDeploy 3.6 prerequisites for Import / Export Web Application slightly changed and more rights need to be given for web management to enable these options again.

Here are the steps to allow it again in Windows Server 2012 R2 (and Windows Server 2016):

1. Using Server Manager get to Add Roles and Features.
2. Pick ‘Management Service’ under Roles/Web Server/Management Tools
3. Either uninstall and reinstall WebDeploy 3.6 or use the Change option and make sure to install the “IIS Deployment Handler” for Web Deploy. This will bring back the Import / Export Web Application option again.

Steps to allow it again in Windows 7:

1. Go to Turn Windows features on or off
2. Under Web Management Tools -> enable IIS Management Service
3. same as above for Windows 2012
   (for Windows 10 you will likely need to run a repair installation on WebDeploy before this solution works)

Comment: This mostly worked for me. I did this on Windows 10 and I didn't really get that #3 for Windows 7 refers to step 3 in the Windows Server R2. After adding the IIS Management Service I had to repair Web Deploy and then it worked perfect.

Comment: For me, it has work when i have installed the Web deploy tools from the Web Platform installer (more details at this link : https://serverfault.com/questions/253292/why-dont-i-have-deploy-actions-available-in-iis-7-manager#answer-776735)

Comment: This worked for me, I had already installed Web Deploy 3.6 first and added the feature in Server Manager and had to repair Web Deploy 3.6 afterwards again. Great answer, have a +1 .

Comment: I had WebDeploy 4.0 installed, which I think originally came with VS 2017. It seems this did not include the UI component by default. I found the [download link](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/e1828da1-907a-46fe-a3cf-f3b9ea1c485c/035860f3c0d2bab0458e634685648385/webdeploy_amd64_en-us.msi) (via https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/324300/web-deploy-40-download.html) and used that to install the "IIS Manager UI Module" component.

Comment: worked for me in Win server 2012 R2. Had to enable the "IIS Management Service" and then reinstall/repair Web Deploy 3.6

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: Thanks @Guy Levy, I noticed the Management Service wasn't installed so already did that but I had Web Deploy already installed.

Enabling (and installing) the IIS Deployment Handler option worked like a charm.

Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 9):

Windows 10:

It uses **Microsoft Web Deploy 4.0**. You can check if it's already installed in the Control panel > Applications.

If it's already installed, and you can't see the "Deploy" option in IIS, you need to reinstall it and, during the setup, **choose the custom or full install, including the UI options**. Perhaps you can do that by choosing repair or Change from the control panel.

According to MS, You should be able to download it from Web Platform Installer, but I only found versions up to 3.6. However, I found this link for an stand-alone installer for 4.0:

[webdeploy_amd64_en-us.msi](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/e1828da1-907a-46fe-a3cf-f3b9ea1c485c/035860f3c0d2bab0458e634685648385/webdeploy_amd64_en-us.msi)

NOTE: I'm using an Spanish Windows, so the name of the options can be wrong. For anyone using a non-English Windows, there is only one installer, and you'll see the menus and options in your language (at least in Spanish).

Comment: Even if you choose the UI options, you still need to make sure that in “Turn Windows features on or off” you enable “Internet Information Services” / “Web Management Tools” / “IIS Management Services”. Then you may need to reinstall/repair Web Deploy 4.0. See [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461305) ;-).

Comment: Thanks, workd for me on Server 2019 + IIS10

Answer (score 7):

Download "Web Platform Installer" from here: 
https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Then search "Web Deployment Tool 2.1". I have it in Spanish like this: 
"Herramienta de implementación web 2.1"

[image]

It just worked for me.

Comment: It may require the IIS Manager to be reopened for the new actions (export & import) to appear in the Actions pane.

Comment: Per Microsoft's notes in the posted link, Web Platform Installer is being retired July 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run IIS as administrator and you should see the Import Web Application" option and The "Export Web Application".